# How to turn a plane into a prism?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender.

I'm wondering if it's possible to turn a plane into a solid figure by transforming it to a prism with the plane as its base? Pretty much like that, with the difference that this is a cube shrinked to a height of 0 and I want to achieve this with a plane:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add reference image of the object you wish to make

Comment: Where does the prism come in? If you add a plane and tab into Edit mode, (select Vertex mode with '1 and select all with 'A' if it isn't already selected), you can just extrude it upwards ('E' > 'Z')  to produce the same effect as you've done with the cube.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused, what do they mean by turn it into a plane from a square then into a prism. Why not just make a plane to begin with?

Comment: That's what I meant. I'm starting with a plane and I want to turn it into a three-dimensional solid figure. F.e. I want to turn a square into a cube, and in general I want to turn any plane polygon into a prism with the original polygon as its base. Thanks to @JohnEason I managed to do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press tab to go into edit mode, press 'A' to select all vertices, and then press 'E' and 'Z' in that order.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnEason pointed out, in Edit Mode with my plane object selected, I can press `E` (and `Z`) to create a three-dimensional prism out of my polygon.

Comment: Good! Glad to help.